# Is it possible to detect where wrapping occurs in html?

Tags: html, text, text-rendering

I'm trying to figure out how many lines would occur given some html (only consisting of spans, break and paragragh tags and text, no images, tables, etc.) and a client width. i would also need to know the text that each line contains. is this possible?

Comment: You might be better off explaining what you're trying to achieve (fit text size to the container maybe?). Right now, it's a little unclear what you want.

Comment: On a webpage, i have a section where a user can type in some rich text. On the server, i'm using a pdf rendering engine to replicate to a pdf EXACTLY what the user input on the client. however, because the client browser may wrap text differently than the pdf engine i'm using. i need to know line for line what is displayed to the user in the rich text area.

Answer (score 0):

What about getting the client height (in pixels) of the rendered content and then dividing that by the height (in pixels) of the font used. Obviously this is limited to using a single font and knowing how tall that font is.

Comment: thanks, Dan. that is a good idea. however, i'll be dealing with rich text. any other ideas?